# pipe is not a function when returning from inside return function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am returning an observable back to my calling method, but I see this -'pipe is not a function' error.

This is my DB layer

```
   querySomthing(request) : Observable<any> {
      // rpc call.
      return this.thirdPartyService.query(request, {}, (error, response) => {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    console.log(response)
                    return of(response); <-- returning observable.
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(error);
                    throw error;
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
                throw error;
            }
         }); 
   }
```

Service layer (Error here- Pipe is not a function)

```
  getinitialData(): Observable<any> {
     //Build request here.
     return this.dbLayer.querySomthing(req).pipe(map((data:any)=>{
       //Process the data here
        return DataObject;
     }));
   }
```

UI component Layer

```
    ngOnInit() {
       this.service.getinitialData().subscribe((d) => {
          UIComponent.datasource = d;
       },
       (error)=>{
          toast(error);
       });
    }
```

When I try with this at the DB layer, it works -

```
   querySomthing(request) : Observable<any> {
      of(someDummyData);
   }
```

In the above use case, I also want to bubble up the exception to the UI toastr.

Comment: What does `this.thirdPartyService.query` return? Can you post a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a blind guest maybe you need to return of an observable in else statement but not 
throw error

```
querySomthing(request) : Observable<any> {
      // rpc call.
      return this.thirdPartyService.query(request, {}, (error, response) => {
            if (!error) {
                try {
                    console.log(response)
                    return of(response); <-- returning observable.
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(error);
                    throw error;
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
                return of();<-- returning observable here also
            }
         }); 
   }
```

Comment: What is your angular and rxjs version ?

Comment: rxjs version -6.5.2

Answer (score 1):

`this.thirdPartyService.query` is not returning an observable. It might be returning undefined or some other object. If you have the source code for the thirdPartyService, you can try stepping into it; otherwise, there's not enough information here to tell you what this service returns or why it does that.